# how to trace a file from where exception is thrown?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, runtimeexception

I am getting an exception in my tomcat's log window, but I am not sure in which file the error is, here is the log output

```
Oct 19, 2012 11:09:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 19, 2012 11:09:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 19, 2012 11:09:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Oct 19, 2012 11:09:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MACT'
Oct 19, 2012 11:09:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'MACT'
Oct 19, 2012 11:09:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MACT'
Oct 19, 2012 11:09:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MACT] in context with path [/MACT] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Thu Oct 18 13"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at com.testcomp.mact.web.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you think the error is related to your coding, then look for the class in your namespace.

In this case `com.testcomp.mact.web.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:70)` does not look as any known framework to me, so I assume it is code under your control.

Comment: i have added a break point to few lines back to line: 70 but code is not stopping there. Why its throwing an exception for a code that is not running?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert String contains date value in to a Long value.Modify the `AuthorizationFilter.doFilter` at line 70 to ensure you are passing valid input `parseLong` call. If you do not have any control with your input value, you can try some thing like below

```
 try {
         long l = Long.parseLong(s);
         System.out.println("long l = " + l);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         log.error("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage()); 
          //Redirect your request to error page saying invalid input

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

com.testcomp.mact.web.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:70)  - -- here method doFilter(...) line no 70.. you are trying to convert the string Thu Oct 18 13 to Long. so that's the error.